# how to simplify a log likelihood function

Tags: log-likelihood

[image]

How to simplify/ get the log likehood of this?
I understand basically the idea is to get the LN of both sides and simplify??

Comment: I believe that in the numerator  of right hand side, instead of $y$ you have $y_i$, is this correct?

Comment: Yep is correct as given.